# How to input a check mark into IDEA only by using keyboard instead copying from website? For example the check mark is ✓ or ✗

Tags: intellij-idea, input, keyboard, symbols, display

I get the ✓ and ✗ from website. I want to input them only by keyboard. How I deal with it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use Unicode hex value inside your println statement:

```
System.out.println(se.execute() == 1 +2 * (9 - 5) ? "\u2713" : "\u2717");
```

`\u2713` is ✓

`\u2717` is ✗

Also, It's possible to put such types of symbols by using keyboard shortcuts:

E.g. in Windows: `Alt +2713` and `Alt +2717`